# Upgrade RAM on Compaq Presario 5000

Tags: memory

I've got a Compaq Presario and it has got only 640 mb of RAM memory. Can I upgrade it to 1 or 2 gb without any problems? (The computer has got a Pentium 4 at 2 ghz and Ubuntu 11.10, but it is a little old (7 or 8 years).

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem. Ubuntu wil notice the new ram and wil use it accordingly. If you use hibernate (don't think so on an old computer) than you should consider to increase your swap partition.

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/), who have a very detailed and well updated catalog. When you find your model apart from the ram chips and models that are compatible with your computer, you can also find information about the maximum ram it can hold and so on.